# Why does the Google Calendar API returns inconsistent events when time-constrained?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to query Google Calendar though its [REST API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/). After having authenticated I [request events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) between `timeMin` and `timeMax`. In the case below, this is +/- 7 days from 'now' (between `2015-09-30T14:19:46.595026+02:00` and `2015-10-14T14:19:46.594026+02:00`):

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer the-token-I-got-and-which-is-OK' 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/something_correct@group.calendar.google.com/events?timeMax=2015-10-14T14%3A19%3A46.594026%2B02%3A00&timeMin=2015-09-30T14%3A19%3A46.595026%2B02%3A00'
```

As a result, I get two events - but the times are wrong:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
(...)
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
(...)
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2015-01-09T07:00:00+01:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Paris"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2015-01-09T07:15:00+01:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Paris"
   },
(...)
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
(...)
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2015-01-10T07:30:00+01:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Paris"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2015-01-10T07:45:00+01:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Paris"
(...)
  }
 ]
}
```

There are two events from **January**. They do exist in the calendar and were the first two events in that calendar (they are recurrent events, with no end date).

**Why aren't the time constraints effective?**

If I remove the time constraints I get more events but still not all of them (which I suppose may be a limitation o the API, requiring some scrolling - I have not investigated that point as my time constraints would match about 10 entries only). The dates are varied, but closer to January than to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `singleEvents` parameter, which is `False` by default.

> Whether to expand recurring events into instances and only return
>   single one-off events and instances of recurring events, but not the
>   underlying recurring events themselves. Optional. The default is
>   False.